# Recommended tree type for breadth-first search

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

During an interview I was asked what the recommended type of tree was if you were going to implement a breadth-first search.

I couldn't really see a particular advantage for anything like red-black/radix/tries.

What's the best kind to use?

Comment: "Best" in what way? A [left-child right-sibling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) representation is pretty convenient for breadth-first search of a general tree. Was he asking specifically about binary trees, or trees in general?

Comment: He wouldn't really be drawn on it...based on the team/product I would suspect this is something they've already implemented, and he wanted to see if I would land on the same thing - which is tough without being part of the whole discussion!
A multi-way tree seems applicable to the problem he described (storing numbers bucketed along one dimension, then another, then another etc).

Comment: However, having read your link, I'm not clear why it's the best - do you mean simply for ease of implementation, because you just follow down one side to get the first layer?

Comment: The question is unclear. Should you bf-search a tree, or should you use a tree to implement generic bf-search? If the former, I would opt for a linled list of nodes arranged by level, with each node having pointers to their children and parent . If the latter, then the answer is none, I don't need a tree to do a bf-search.

Comment: @Oli: I didn't say it was the best. I said that it can be convenient. And, yes, because it's a simple matter of following the right node to get the siblings at a particular level. If he was a good interviewer, he wanted you to discuss benefits and drawbacks of different tree representations. and ways of doing a BFS.  If he was a poor interviewer, he was looking for an absolute answer to a question that wasn't sufficiently specified.

Comment: @JimMischel Agreed. I'll give him the benefit of the doubt! Within the constraints I think this is a good answer, you should post it as one :)

Answer (score 0):

I would immediately ask two questions.

1. Why are you doing a breath-first search in the first place?
2. What else are you doing with the tree at the same time?

In general the reason to do breadth-first search is because you want an answer that is close to the root.  Your tree should be shaped in such a way that "close to the root" matches your criteria for doing the search.  And then you need a tree whose shape matches that criteria.  Which is generally very different from having the shape be optimized to minimize distance from root to any leaf (like red-black trees do).

And the concern about what else you are doing is that if this is a shared data structure, you're locking the whole thing.  Therefore think carefully through what locking and contention you will have, and how you'll handle it.